# Pentaho Kettle - FTP Download(check if file download is complete)

Tags: ftp, pentaho, kettle

I am not understanding how to implement this in Linux based systems. I have job which downloads the files from FTP and places it in local systems and my other job(has to run in parallel) has to check if the file is **completely** downloaded and then only process the file(transform) and emit the results. I am not able to check if the file is completely downloaded or not from the server. Any inputs??

Answer (score 0):

Check the [docs](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Check+Files+Locked) on the `Check files locked` job step. See if that will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Brian. But there is no guarantee that it would work in Linux systems. I could sucessfully change the name of the file while contents are being written to the same file .

Comment: Then you should probably edit your question to include operating system information. This kind of thing is highly OS specific.